# How to assign separated volumes to each container? [Docker-swarm] [Hyperledger]

Tags: docker-swarm, hyperledger, docker-volume

Generally, Hyperledger use an internal /var/hyperledger/ to store the database for each container. And we actually need to mount this directory outside of the container.

When running a bare command docker run or docker-compose, we can specify this parameter separately or even use the docker compose file.

**Question:**
Since I may need to try Hyperledger with the docker swarm (Docker 1.12), and each Hyperledger container must not uses the same shared volume with any others. So, how can I specify the separated volumes to each container using Docker swarm mode?

```
$ docker service create ...
```